# I can't find a file in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: find

i used the code in terminal

```
sudo mv filename.jpg /usr/share/backgrounds
```

but when i check there, it is missing, also can't find in /home

Comment: note: if you made a typo within the destination folder, you may have moved the file as another name in another location !

For example: `sudo mv filename.jpg /usr/share/background` would move your **file** filename.jpg to /usr/share/background (and 'background' would be a file, not a folder).

Comment: can't find it. Is there a way to check where i have moved my files, i mean their location..
the last one is showing my file is moved on that time.

    sudo ls -la /home

terminal display was
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Nov 17 08:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root  4096 Dec  1 13:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Nov 17 08:54 .ecryptfs
drwx------ 29 muin muin 12288 Dec  6 22:52 muin

Comment: No, but you can look through your `bash` command history.  Simply give the command `history | less` and bash will spew all your old commands out.  Scroll to the bottom (try the [End] key) and start looking for the relevant command.

Answer (score 1):

if you typed the command as above do this

```
ls -l /usr/share
```

you may have 2 backgrounds, one being a directory and the other being the jpg having been renamed to backgrounds without a file extension.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You cannot create a file with same name of an existing directory.

Comment: My apologies you are correct.  Then the only question is if the backgrounds directory even existed prior to the run of the command.  If so then the file should have moved into that directory.